# How to add a variable to a twig field template?

Tags: theming, 8

On a node page I would like to add the node title to the output alongside another another field (the example field).

I have created a new `field--field-example.html.twig` but am unable to access the node title variable as it is not available in the field template.

I need to add the variables into the theme preprocess: `themename.theme`.

How do I add the variable in `themename.theme` and what would be the corresponding entry in the `field--field-example.html.twig` ?

Comment: Use hook_preprocess_node to extract the value from the field that you would like to use in the template.

Comment: @IvanJaros, I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you asked about passing the node title as a variable via the .theme file, you could use [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8) to do something like this:

```
  function themename_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_example') {
      $variables['node_title'] = $variables['element']['#object']->getTitle();
    }
  }
```

then in your `field--field-example.html.twig` you could simply just use `{{node_title}}` to render the node title.

Also see 4k4's answer below.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to include the one provided by 4k4 as it is correct but my edit was declined as it was deemed not relevant...

Comment: @TaylorTaff who approves edits? I never saw it. Will attempt to edit to include answer below.

Comment: @Janey many users with enough badges can review such edits. I have bookmarked your answers for future review. One more question: Are you guys sure that `$variables['element']['#object']->getTitle();` is catchable in `preprocess_field` ? Because this would actually answer my question over here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197497/how-to-hand-over-value-of-field-1-to-class-array-of-field-2-programmatically-in

Answer (score 11):

There is a node object available in the variables of the field template, so you don't need a preprocess function.

To get the title from the node in a field template:

```
{{ element['#object'].label }}
```

Comment: This answers the question but as the other answer by Janey will be more useful I added this to that answer and marked as accepted.

Comment: But your question was under the wrong assumption: " but am unable to access the node title variable as it is not available in the field template."

Comment: Yes 4k4, you are correct, my question was incorrect.