# How to hand over value of field 1 to class array of field 2 programmatically in .theme

Tags: nodes, 8, theming

#### Motivation

Context between template variable arrays is an old problem already known in D6 and 7 on theming level. What about D8 now? Any light on the horizon? Any chance to make this avaible without using *Views module* tweaks and work arounds?

#### Let's use an example:

Default standart content type **Article** has 4 input fields:

- label (title)
- body (main text area)
- image
- tags (terms, entity reference)

This content type also has an alternative *Manage Fields Display* setting for the *Teaser view mode*, where the image field formatter is set up using a smaller *Image Style* and with the option to link to the file or full node page. This creates an `<a>` element with url but without title or any other attributes around the Article image markup in Teaser view mode.

#### The question:

How can I hand over e.g. the first value of the tags (input terms) programmatically to a classes array of the wrapping `<a>` element?

In `node--view--frontpage.html.twig` this ...

```
`<a href="#" class="image icon fa-{{ (content.field_tags['0']['#title']) }}">{{ content.field_image }}</a>`
```

... works. Sure, because we grab it from the page variable. But `image-formatter.html.twig` is deeper nested inside the whole template system and it would be an overload to have the whole page variable array available here. Of course it is not there.

#### My assumption was to use the following preprocess functions:

- `function theme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {}` and or
- `function theme_preprocess_image_formatter(&$variables) {}`

#### The problem:

It seems - even if `_preprocess_image_formatter` has been suggested in the twig comments of the `image-formatter.html.twig` - there is 1.) no place to pass a string to any kind of *attributes* array for the `<a>` element in this twig file since the array has no given place for that. 2.) The hand over. How? Global vars are mostly not the best solution.

The core template code of `image-formatter.html.twig`:

```
{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ image }}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ image }}
{% endif %}
```

The drafted alternation to demonstrate the needed effect:

```
{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}"{{ some defined attributes }}>{{ image }}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ image }}
{% endif %}
```

NOTE: adding values manually and directly in the twig theme file like

```
<a href="{{ url }}" class="hallo-classes">{{ image }}</a>`
```

shows that this is the right twig template. But it seems there is no way to get other values handed over (here), since `_preprocess_image_formatter` $variables array doesn't know any values of other fields of course (like of **tags** term field). And `_preprocess_field()` doesn't reach the image formatter level so that an addition to the attributes array rather affects the surrounding div but not the `<a>` element.

Comment: Maybe this is rather a feature discussion on Drupal.org, not sure. And probably theming level is not the right place for that functionality. It is arguable if this handing over of field values to theme classes should happen on theme or module level.  But it is not arguable that this functionality would be the only exceptable reason for the whole HTML container mass in Drupals theme output. Otherwise we have no flexibilty in the choice of HTML/CSS whatever frameworks or boilerplates. There should be an obvious way to hand over such values to change the classes of markup in the same context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Context between template variable arrays is an old problem already
>   known in D6 and 7 on theming level. What about D8 now? Any light on
>   the horizon?

No, there is no light on the horizon, quite the contrary. Because of the concept of nested render elements, that are rendered independently. In D8 it is getting far more complicated because of the dynamic cache. And it wouldn't work at all with the plans for the future with placeholders and lazy building.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts on this! but doesn't your answer interfere slidely with your answer over [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189605/how-to-add-a-variable-to-a-twig-field-template/189880#189880)? Maybe we should accept work arounds. I am not sure if my question maybe is too static then...

Comment: Caching in D8 will make such things more difficult, but I don't think you would get in trouble with the node title in this case.